# <span> as part of <a> tag

Tags: html, email, html-email

I need to write a URL link in an email editor.

```
<a href="https://a_link.com?em=[email]>Link to click</a>
```

[email] is a placeholder for the recipient's email address and on this email platform, the email placeholder is obtained using

```
<span data-redactor-type="variable">email</span>
```

How can I have something that is conceptually like the code below but actually works. I think characters need to be escaped or through the use of a variable???

```
    <a href="https://a_link.com?em=<span data-redactor-type="variable">email</span>>Link to click</a>
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you meant this?

```js
const link = document.querySelector('a[href$="[email]"]');
link.href=link.href
  .replace('\[email\]',document.querySelector('[data-redactor-type="variable"]').textContent);
console.log(link.href)
```

```html
<a href="https://a_link.com?em=[email]">Link to click</a>
<span data-redactor-type="variable">a@b.com</span>
```

Or did you really mean this?

```js
const link = document.querySelector('a[href$="[email]"]');
link.href=link.href
  .replace('\[email\]',encodeURIComponent(document.querySelector('[data-redactor-type="variable"]').outerHTML));
console.log(link.href)
```

```html
<a href="https://a_link.com?em=[email]">Link to click</a>
<span data-redactor-type="variable">a@b.com</span>
```

Comment: He said editor. Not email, you are of course correct if the link ends up in an email there can not be script in the result

Comment: Yes but not all editors support scripts either. Most are restricted to HTML. If he is just a user then he will not be able to use the script.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <span>email&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="https://a_link.com?em=<span data-redactor-type="variable">Link to click</a></span>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.